# Perl syntax sigil

Tags: perl, syntax

May I know what's the use of the `&` in front of subs when without it, the subs are still able to run.

And also, the `my` in front of perl variables.

I know it's for strict language syntax or what not, but why don't they just make it a standard that every variable needs to be declared by a `my`?

**EDIT**

Thanks for all of your discussions/answers, I wish to accept many of your answers, but since I'm can only accept one, I will accept the one where other users might understand with ease.

Comment: For future readers: Eric Strom's answer is the only one that’s fully correct. The prototype defeating behavior of `&` is important to know.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In Perl, function calls have been optimized to not require the `&` sigil at all times.  When you declare a subroutine:

```
sub hello {print "world\n"}
```

You can call it as `hello;` or `hello();` or `&hello();` which will all do the same thing.

If your subroutine takes arguments, it is a little different:

```
sub hello {print "Hello, @_!\n"}

hello 'World';   # prints 'Hello, World!'
hello('World');  # same
&hello('World'); # same

hello;    # prints 'Hello, !'
&hello(); # same
&hello;   # different, uses whatever was in @_ when hello was called

@_ = 'Bob';

hello;    # prints 'Hello, !'
&hello(); # prints 'Hello, !'
&hello;   # prints 'Hello, Bob!'
```

So as you can see, using the `&` sigil is largely redundant, except in the case where there is no argument list.  In that case, the subroutine is called with the current values in `@_`.

The `&` sigil also has another special behavior, related to Perl's prototypes.  Say you were writing your own `keys` function, and wanted it to behave like Perl's:

```
sub mykeys (\%) {keys %{$_[0]}}
```

Here the `(\%)` prototype tells perl that the first argument to `mykeys` must be a literal hash (which will be passed in as a hash reference).

```
my $hashref = {...};

say for mykeys %$hashref;
```

If for some reason you needed to get around this requirement (generally not the best idea), you could write this:

```
say for &mykeys( $hashref );  # note that there is no `%`
```

In this case, adding `&` before the sub disables the prototype check and any subsequent actions that it would have performed (like taking the reference).  In this usage, `&` is basically an assertion that you know exactly what arguments `mykeys` needs, and you don't want perl getting in the way.

In general, using `&` on subroutines should be avoided, unless you explicitly want one of the behaviors I mentioned above.

Finally, `&` is also needed when you are refering to the actual code reference:

```
my $coderef = \&hello;
```

or

```
if (defined &hello) {print "hello is defined\n"}  # but is not called
```

---

As others have mentioned, the `my` operator declares variables in the current lexical scope.  It is required when the `use strict;` pragma is loaded.  Perl has two types of variables, lexical variables declared with `my`, and package variables.

`my` variables live in what is called a lexical pad, which is a storage space created by Perl each time a new scope is introduced.  Package variables live in the global symbol table.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

$main::foo = 5;   # package variable

{ # scope start
   my $foo = 6;

   print "$foo, $main::foo\n"; # prints '6, 5';
} # scope end

print "$foo, $main::foo\n";  # syntax error, variable $foo is not declared
```

You can use the `our` keyword to create a lexical alias to a global variable:

```
use strict;


our $foo = 5;  # $main::foo == $foo


{ # scope start
   my $foo = 6;

   print "$foo, $main::foo\n"; # prints '6, 5';
} # scope end

print "$foo, $main::foo\n";  # prints '5, 5' 
                             # since $foo and $main::foo are the same
```

Comment: Thanks for your very comprehensive answer and explanations

Comment: @Eric Strom: You say the & should generally not be used. However, I have noticed that emacs does nice syntax highlight if you use &sub for subroutine calls. Is there a specific downside or danger to using them for this purpose? Or, preferably, is there a way to get emacs to syntax highlight subs without it?

Comment: @YGomez => the danger with using `&` all the time is that `&mysub` and `&mysub()` do VERY different things (the former calling the sub with the current value of `@_`, and the latter calling the sub with an empty argument list).  Since the two names are so visually similar, it can be easy to mistake one for the other, which will lead to hard to diagnose bugs.  Since Perl does not require the `&` in most places, it is thus better to leave it out, and only use it when you explicitly want the behavior it can provide.  As far as emacs goes, I am sure there are other syntax highlighting mode.

Comment: It's also worth noting that `&foo;` is different in execution to `foo(@_);` -- the former is more like a goto, leaving the stack in place which, in rare and very specific cases like deep tail recursion, can be a big performance win.

Answer (score 8):

The `my` limits the variable to the current scope. With the `use strict` pragma, which you should use, you *must* declare the variables (e.g. with `my`). The alternative to go without exists for flexibility reasons for very short scripts.

The `&` is seldom used anymore since Perl default-interprets sigil-less words as subroutines, but is useful if you want to create a reference to subroutine.

```
sub say_hi { print "hi\n" }
my $sub_ref = \&say_hi;
```

Comment: simple and straightforward answer.. Thanks for clarifying =)

Answer (score 5):

> May I know what's the use of the & in front of subs when without it, the subs are still able to run.

Backwards compatibility with Perl 4

> And also, the my in front of perl variables.

It sets block scope

> I know it's for strict language syntax or what not, but why don't they just make it a standard that every variable needs to be declared by a my?

1. Backwards compatibility (hence `use strict;` disallowing bare variable declarations)
2. Variables can also be declared with `our` or `local`

Comment: also it's easier to write 1 liners with `perl -e` without `my`.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to know how to write modern Perl, may I recommend you read [Modern Perl](http://www.onyxneon.com/books/modern_perl/)?
You can buy a dead tree version or download an electronic version for free.

Comment: Seems like a good read. I'll give it a go.. This question is more of a thing that's bugging me as I saw many different websites with different implementations. It's probably my own fault to not read their dates of posting.

Answer (score 0):

`&` has still pretty good distinction: calling with it (`&YourSub`) makes current `@_` visible to called sub too. Anyway, i use it in my scripts mostly  for clarity reasons: it makes clear, which are my own functions and which functions from core or modules.

About `my`. Every tutorial and doc suggest to use `use strict;` pragma, so you have then declare your varaible with `my` too. So, the situation from my point of view is pretty backwards: if scope is so important for best practicies, it would be normal that variables are scoped by default (like we say with `my` now) and when we really need global variables, we should declare them as that. I understand it is perl's legacy, but still it is against Perl's ideology to keep out redundancy. Using `my` every time for declaring could be overridden by some sort of pragma. [Sorry, robobooga, maybe going too far from your question]

Comment: Unfortunately, if, say, Perl 5.14 would enable `strict` by default, then all existing Perl code which *doesn't* `use strict` is instantly broken.  Perl 5.12 goes a little way in this direction: if you `use 5.012`, then `strict` is enabled automagically.

Comment: @mscha: yes, i understand, there is no way to make strict-pragma default for every script wrote out there, but i dream about pragma, where all variables are by default local in their scope and when i need global variables, i declare them explicitly with `our`

Comment: I actually don't mind using `my` so often. When I have a variable in the outermost scope and also declare a function with a variable of the same name (for clarity, in its own way) I know that I am getting a new variable in the sub, because now I have to think NOT to use my rather than thinking to use it.